# In TeamBuild 2010, is it possible to do Gated Check-ins in a .NET/VB6 build environment?

Tags: .net, vb6, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm interested in using the Gated Checkins in my build process however I have .NET code and VB6 code. Will Gated Checkins work with both sets of code?

Comment: If your V6 code builds without gated checkins, then why would it not build _with_ them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely. You will need to customize the build process template to call the VB6 compiler instead of MSBuild as appropriate but you can do pretty much anything you want in a Gated Check-In build in TFS.  You define what "success" actually means.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to install VB6 on your build server and then to either mod one of the xaml templates or add your own msbuild file (to be called by your build def) to your source which calls something like VB6task from http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/documentation or via an Exec task like this:

`<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\VB6zzzz" Command='"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.exe" /make zzz.vbp /d composer=0:ADO=1 /outdir "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Binaries" /out $(MakeLog)' ContinueOnError="false" />`